# Copy/Paste Visible(filtered) Cells to Text (.txt) File

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked all over the forums and could not find specific code to do exactly this (only pieces of code that probably put together would do what I want).

Would it be possible to do the following:

- Filter Column B for "R/R"
- Copy **Visible** cells  in Column P of Sheets("Test1")  -- this sheet pulls its data from an external access query and is setup as a table (not sure if this matters)
- Paste as is to a text file in a specific destination 
  (By as is I mean how it would look if you manually copied and pasted the cell range into a text file)

I wanted to do this with the Write or Print and not simply copy to the clipboard and paste.

Please see below for my code. It filters and copies/pastes to the desired text file however it stops at the first filtered cell, i.e. there are 5 rows with "R/R" in column B (571,4213,4510,5191,5192), but it only pastes cell P571.

Sub abc()

```
Sheets("Test1").ListObjects("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database").Range. _
    AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="R/R"

LastRow = Sheets("Test1").Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim myrng As Range, i, j

filename = "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output.txt"

Open filename For Output As #1

Set myrng = Sheets("Test1").Range("P2:P" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    Print #1, lineText
Next i

Close #1
```

End Sub

**EDIT: The code provided by the user initially worked, but there appears to be a bug.
Whenever there is "R/R" in one row after the other (e.g. Cell B122 & B123), it pastes the data from Cell P122 & P123 to the text file one after the other with a comma instead of moving it to the next line in the text file which is what I wanted. 
I want it pasted into a text file like this below (PLEASE IGNORE the dashes "-", I needed to place them to put the # on another line in this thread):**

- 1234564789
- 46546546489
- 134123465465
- 7897897897
- 465465654
- 789789645
- 87978978879
- 465465465

However, it is pasting it like this with a comma on one of the lines and placing it beside another number:

- 1234564789
- 46546546489
- 134123465465
- 7897897897
- 465465654, 789789645
- 87978978879
- 465465465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop through your range [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197473.aspx) collection

you can try this (commented) code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    With Sheets("Test1") '<--| reference relevant sheet
        With .ListObjects("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database").Range '<--| reference its relevant Table
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="R/R" '<--| filter it on its 2nd column (column "B" if table starts from column "A"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set myRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'set filtered range, if any, 1st row (headers) excluded
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| get rows back visible
    End With

    If Not myRng Is Nothing Then WriteFile "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output.txt", myRng '<--| write txt file if any filtered Table rows
End Sub


Sub WriteFile(filePath As String, rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim area As Range

    On Error GoTo ExitSub '<--| be sure to properly close txt file
    Open filePath For Output As #1

    For Each area In rng.Areas '<--| loop through range 'Areas' collection
        For i = 1 To area.rows.Count '<--| loop through current 'area' rows
            Print #1, Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(area.rows(i).Value)), ",") '<--|collect current Table row cells into an array and then join its content into a string with comma (",") as separator
        Next i
    Next area

ExitSub:
    Close #1
End Sub
```

---

for column P only:

**edited** after OP's clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim arr As Variant

    With Sheets("Test1") '<--| reference relevant sheet
        With .ListObjects("Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database").Range '<--| reference its relevant Table
            .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="R/R" '<--| filter it on its 2nd column (column "B" if table starts from column "A"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then Set myRng = .Offset(1, 15).Resize(.rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'set filtered range, if any, 1st row (headers) excluded
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| get rows back visible
    End With

    If Not myRng Is Nothing Then WriteFile "C:\Users\bob\Desktop\output.txt", myRng '<--| write txt file if any filtered Table rows
End Sub


Sub WriteFile(filePath As String, rng As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim area As Range
    Dim lineText As String

    On Error GoTo ExitSub '<--| be sure to properly close txt file
    Open filePath For Output As #1

    For Each area In rng.Areas '<--| loop through range 'Areas' collection
        For i = 1 To area.rows.Count '<--| loop through current 'area' rows
            lineText = IIf(i = 1, "", lineText & vbCrLf) & area(i, 1).Value
        Next i
        Print #1, lineText
    Next area

ExitSub:
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.... It's pasting all of the columns, not just column P, but its filtering correctly

Comment: see edits for column P only. not so clear how you want those single column values printed. but by now you should be able to adjust code by yourself

Comment: @jpv5, 20 days ago you marked my post as the answer saying "it does exactly what I need". Today you unmark it saying "The code provided by the user initially worked, but there appears to be a bug...". SO is not to provide software with "lifetime" and "whatever the data" warranty, it is for people trying to help other people with their coding attempts and drive them in the proper direction. If your current data give you problems you should post a _new_ question with detailed description of your data and _your_ coding efforts. And leave this one checked. thank you.

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to achieve the same result, only using more lines of data. I am trying to do what I wanted to achieve in the first place. Your code worked using a small data set, but when using more data it did not work and caused the bug mentioned in my edit -- i.e. asking the question again would only flood the forum with a duplicate since I am trying to do the same thing only with more lines of data than what was tested. I am completely clueless as to why one line shows up next to the other with  comma in the text file when the rest were fine. I see nothing in the code to cause this

Comment: Well, you gave no data description whatsoever in your question and demand the solution to be 4-season fit! Moreover you're not showing any effort neither at analyzing the given code nor at giving meaningful description about data causing unwanted behavior. But, well, that's your question and so suit yourself.

Comment: Apologies, I just didn't understand the issue -- I am a complete rookie with vba and I am here because of that. I found out the exact issue. Whenever there is "R/R"  in one row after the other (e.g. Cell B122 & B123), it pastes the data from Cell P122 & P123 to the text file one after the other with a comma instead of moving it to the next line in the text file which is what I wanted.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect!